# How Can I Tell If JMeter Needs More Heap To Produce "Correct" Results?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jmeter

This is a theoretical question that just occurred to me.

Normally when running an JMeter load test, I find the default heap settings are adequate.

Sometimes when running an intensive JMeter load test, JMeter will throw an OutOfMemory exception, indicating it requires more heap (normally).

I'm concerned about the cases inbetween these two. If JMeter does *not* throw an OutOfMemory, is there any way to reassure myself that garbage-collecting (on JMeter's side) did not adversely affect the results? Do I have to monitor the gc logs everytime I run JMeter?

I suppose the more practical side of this is; can I compare output from two separate JMeter tests where Jmeter used different heap-sizes?

EDIT: One thing I have noticed, is that the Jmeter UI has an icon to indicate that the GC Overhead Limit has been breached. But this comes from the JVM and is triggered where 98% of CPU time is used doing GC and I reckon my results would be skewed long before I reach this point.

Comment: You can monitor GC pauses through visual VM. I doubt the load would be so high that it affects the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If JMeter does not throw an OutOfMemory, is there any way to reassure myself that garbage-collecting (on JMeter's side) did not adversely affect the results? Do I have to monitor the gc logs everytime I run JMeter?

The simple way to determine if the heap size affected the results is to run the tests again with a larger heap size and see if it makes any difference.  This applies equally to application you are testing and to the JMeter JVM.

If you do have evidence there is a problem, you could changing the JMeter JVM settings to use a low pause collector.  This might reduce the number of apparent "outlier" request times ... if they are caused by JMeter-side GC pauses.  But it could (in theory) also reduce the overall throughput of the JMeter JVM, and hence the average rate at which it can make requests.

If the application and JMeter are running on the same hardware, the other thing you could try is adjusting process priorities to ensure that the JMeter process is not CPU starved.